# Sending command on serial port using c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a little application that sends a command over a serial port and write the response in a label.
If I send a ENTER character

```
inputData = "\r\n\";
port.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputData), 0, 1);
```

the response is the last string that was generated by the device I communicate with.
If I send something like

```
inputData = "S1\r\n";
port.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputData), 0, 1);
```

the label stays empty.
The second command is the one that I need to send and in Putty terminal works well.
Is there a way to send the same thing via port.Write?

Comment: Perhaps you want to [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) the response from the device *after* you write the data on it?

Comment: @J.Salas I read with port.ReadExisting and write the result in a label. The label changes only when I write the ENTER character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Write method definition is

```
void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
```

In your second example you are only sending the character 'S' - you are not sending the remainder of the string. The third parameter is the number of characters in the string to send (the second is the start offset).

Maybe modify your code allong the lines of

```
var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputData);
port.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

The fact the first example worked probably indicates that all you need to send is '\r' & the '\n' is not required.

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote your comment but I mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad to be of help.